# Alljoyn Control-Panels Not Rendering in Dashboard 14.12

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, alljoyn

I have Alljoyn Dashboard 14.12 on my Samsung Galaxy Note that I simply downloaded from the play store.

I've noticed that, while the dashboard is able to find and onboard Alljoyn devices, it does not render their control-panels.

I've found this to be true on both COTS devices (LIFX 1000 bulbs) as well as raw code that I've run on a Raspberry Pi 2B.  Specifically, I can run the ACServer example and it shows up on the dashboard (just like the LIFX bulbs), but the control-panel does not render.

Is Alljoyn dashboard 14.12 not compatible with the most recent Alljoyn release?